# How to get back to GUI of ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04. Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.

After successful installation keyboard and mouse were not working.

I restarted my system and I see something like GNU bash (like Linux server Administration - Black screen) with error:

```
device descriptor read/64 error 110
```

How can I fix this and get back to graphical interface?